# MySQL Update with IF-Condition treats 0 like '' or NULL

Tags: mysql

Given 2 tables tbl1 and tbl2. Values in tbl1 should be updated/replaced with values from tbl2 in corresponding rows, if the values in tbl2 aren't NULL or empty strings (''). For any reason, MySQL (and MariaDB) are treating 0 values as it were empty strings or NULL values. Is there any way to get around it?

**Edit:** this is just a simple example. In reality I don't know the type of the field. It's an automated PHP script which generates the SET-statements of the query for each field that exists in both tables. That can be string or (tiny)integer fields, text etc. I guess that the script should check then the type of the field and decide how to build the IF-part of the statement depending on the field's type. When I understood the comments right, I can't expect an useful result of a string-like comparison on an integer field. //

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/573fc

```
UPDATE
  tbl1 t1,
  tbl2 t2 
SET 
  t1.val = IF(t2.val != '' AND t2.val IS NOT NULL, t2.val, t1.val)
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.id;
```

Let's assume for tbl1:

```
id | val
1  | 1
```

Let's assume for tbl2:

```
id | val
1  | 0
```

Now I want to update val in tbl1 with the value from val of tbl2, if val in tbl2 isn't NULL neither an empty string. Since val in tbl2 is 0, val in tbl1 should become 0, too. But this doesn't happen. I don't know why. If val in tbl2 is 1, 2, 3 or whatever else different than 0, NULL or '', the query above works fine.

The real query is more complex and updates more fields, depending of their values. But this part is the one that bothers me. And since the fields can have different types (strings, integers, dates and so on), I can't really work "around it".

**Edit 2/Solution/Work around:**

Since I couldn't change much on the code nor the DB, I came up with this solution. It's maybe not the prettiest one and far away from being neat and clean, but it works.

```
UPDATE
  tbl1 t1,
  tbl2 t2 
SET 
  t1.val = IF((t2.val != '' AND t2.val IS NOT NULL) OR t2.val = '0', t2.val, t1.val)
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.id;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in this predicate:

```
t2.val != ''
```

This evalutes to `true` when `t2.val = 0`. This is due to *implicit type coversion*. Check [**this demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b4f76/3) to see for yourslef.

The predicate is not necessary, since `val` is of type `tinyint(3)` (according to table definitions given in the provided sql fiddle). So leave it out of your `UPDATE` statement and you're good to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your query much more simply as:

```
UPDATE tbl1 t1 JOIN
       tbl2 t2 
       ON t1.id = t2.id
    SET t1.val = t2.val
    WHERE t2.val IS NOT NULL;
```

A Giorgos explains, the main problem with your query is the comparison of a numeric column to a string -- and the resulting implicit type conversion.

However, this version also:

- Fixes the logic to use explicit `JOIN` syntax, so the intention of the query is clearer.
- Moves the comparison logic to the `WHERE` clause.  This makes the query more efficient, because it does not attempt to update all rows.

Comment: Well, this was just a short example to point out the main problem. In fact it's a much more complex query with multiple tables involved and over 200 hundred fields that are compared and updated on the left side, if they have a value on the right side. But I understand your main point.

Answer (score 0):

if column val in tbl2 is an integer field, so you cannot put '' int it, it will return to 0. so you can only check for null values only. and in this case your query will work correctly.

```
 UPDATE
  tbl1 t1,
  tbl2 t2 
SET 
  t1.val = IF( t2.val IS NOT NULL, t2.val, t1.val)
WHERE
  t1.id = t2.id;
```